# How to add Logo image inside Toolbar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi new to Xamarin android. Have this question:

1) How to add an image Logo inside the Toolbar?

What is the Image Logo size interms of W X H ?

Here the toolBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">      
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"          
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"          
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"          
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"          
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Thanks

---- Update : solved

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"          
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"          
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"          
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"          
  android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<ImageView    
android:id="@+id/toolbarimage"    
android:layout_marginTop="12dp"    
android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"    
android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:layout_gravity="center"    
android:src="@drawable/Logo" />
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to add an image Logo inside the Toolbar?

First, you need to create a custom Toolbar correctly, you can follow the [Replacing the Action Bar](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/toolbar/part-1-replacing-the-action-bar/) to create a custom Toolbar.

Then, you can simply add any elements inside of your Toolbar layout:

Toolbar.axml(`house.png` in `Resources/drawable` folder):

```
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/house" />
</Toolbar>
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
[Activity(Label = "ToolbarDemo", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar.Title = "";
    }
}
```

And you will get something like this:
[image]

> What is the Image Logo size interms of W X H ?

The `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` determine the size of the `ImageView` ,but by default, the image won't adjust itself by `ImageView`. You can change this behavior by setting `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`:

```
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/house" />
</Toolbar>
```

For details about Android Layout, please refer to Layout Parameters section of [Android Layout Document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

Comment: It is really really happy to see your solution. Please help me as I have trouble installing V7 appCompat. here my step, I right click Component under the project to get V7 AppCompat. At first all the DLL with  Xamarin.Android.Support.compat and other Xamarin.Android.Support......r imported in Component and Reference folders. After a while, WHY there is a Yellow Triangle warning sign attached to all the DLL begin with Xamarin.Android.Support  in Reference folder? what this means? When I right click Reference folder and select Nuget Manager, it show V7 AppCompat is installed. What is happening?

Comment: Some dependencies probably not fully installed. Please try uninstall all the nuget package and install `xamarin.android.support.v7.appcompat` through nuget again.

Comment: first get support v7 Appcompat via Component. When click on reference folder, it will show v7 Appcompat :  1) Installed 25.1.1  -- Uninstall btn <br/> 2. version 25.1.0 -- Update btn<br/>  I need to click Update btn to get 25.1.0 if not I get the YELLOW triangle warning sign. Is 25.1.1 has problem? Must use version 25.1.0 ? Thank

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you described. I can install and use `v7 Appcompat 25.1.1` without any problem. Could you please share a basic project demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I m using Vs2015 Update3. I have uploaded the image withYELLOW triangles.After click update to 25.1.0, thing back to normal.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How can I change the android:src value of the ImageView from code? At certain points I would like to show a different image. Any idea?