# How to center image in ios toolbar in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Basically I want to center image in the toolbar in my app
I solved it in android by follow this answer

[How to add Logo image inside Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295981/how-to-add-logo-image-inside-toolbar?rq=1)

and result is 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/COE3L.jpg

how can i do this in ios ?

Comment: You can try using [this](https://github.com/stormlion227/SNavigation.Forms) plugin to do it on both iOS and Android.

Comment: is it working fine with you ? @AbsoluteSith

Comment: Yeah I've added a button and it works without any problems.